# Adjust layout React Native

Tags: react-native

I did a layout below:

```
<ScrollView style={{flexDirection:'row'}]>
  <View style={{flex:1}}></View>
  <View style={{flex:1}}></View>
  <View style={{flex:1}}></View>
  <View style={{flex:1}}></View>
  <View style={{flex:1}}></View>
  <View style={{flex:1}}></View>
  <View style={{flex:1}}></View>
</ScrollView>
```

I want 3 columns on each row. But the code print 7 columns.

How to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have it means the 7 views will occupy the same percentage of space along the row. Adding up the flex numbers yields 7. So each `View` will occupy 1/7 of the row.

You can go about a solution in two ways:

(1) Divide up the views into groups of 3 views wrapped inside an outer `View`

(2) Use `flexWrap` and `percentages` for the `width` instead of `flex`.

**Approach 1**

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}></View>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}></View>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}></View>
  </View>
  <View style={{ flex:1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    <View style={{ flex:1 }}></View>
    <View style={{ flex:1 }}></View>
    <View style={{ flex:1 }}></View> 
  </View>
  <View style={{ flex:1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}></View>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }} />
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}/>
  </View>
</View>
```

The approach above requires you enclose three views in an outer view, setting `flexDirection` to row for each outer view so the items inside that container each occupy 1/3 of the space. Note that you have to hardcode two extra views for the last row (unless you use percentage `width` instead of `flex` number).

**Approach 2**

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
  <View style={{ width: '33.333%' }}></View>
  <View style={{ width: '33.333%' }}></View>
  <View style={{ width: '33.333%' }}></View>
  <View style={{ width: '33.333%' }}></View>
  <View style={{ width: '33.333%' }}></View>
  <View style={{ width: '33.333%' }}></View>
  <View style={{ width: '33.333%' }}></View>
</View>
```

In this approach, you don't use the `flex` number. Instead, you apply percentage widths that correspond to ~33.33% of the screen width. Keep in mind you need the `flexWrap` style property to be set to `wrap`. **Note** you need to set the `height` for each view otherwise you might see nothing.

> Make sure to apply `backgroundColor` to the different views above during development and debugging otherwise you won't be able to visualize what is going on because they will all have the same background color.